# Mathematical induction for high school maths

Tags: induction

Can someone PLEASE help me with this.
Thank you

The solutions of the equation $z^{100}=1$ are $1, w_1, w_2, w_3, \ldots, w_{99}$.

Prove $1\times w_1\times w_2\times ...\times w_{99} = -1$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I literally have no idea how to tackle this at all:(

Comment: @Kylie Can you use MathJax? I don't understand your question. Also it's important that you show your attempts for to solve this problem,

Comment: Why use induction?

Comment: Your problem is exactly solved here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/115559/732532

Comment: cuz i need to use arithmetic sequences and stuff?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Knowing the roots, you can write $z^{100}-1=0$ as $(z-1)(z-w_1)(z-w_2)\cdots(z-w_{99}) = 0$.

What is the constant term on the left side of each of these equations?

Comment: what do you mean by know the roots?

Comment: actually nevermind i understand that part, z is the constant term?

Comment: No, I mean the term that doesn’t contain any $z$